# Destroy Joyride in Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

Is there a way to destroy the joyride provided by Zurb Foundation problematically. I am trying to destroy the joyride like this

```
$('#joyride-list-location-creation').joyride('destroy');
```

But I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).joyride is not a function(…)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 2.1 of joyride.

There is a 'destroy' function in the [source code](https://github.com/zurb/joyride/blob/master/jquery.joyride-2.1.js#L434)

For my usage, I needed to destroy it when it closed, so I added a call to destroy in the `postRideCallback`.

Like this:

```
$('#incompleteJoyRide').joyride({
        autoStart : true,
        postRideCallback: function () {
            $('#incompleteJoyRide').joyride('destroy');
        },
        modal:true,
        expose: true,
        animate: true
    });
```